# Human Gender Classification- Train and Val accuracy not moving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am having 0.3 million image in my Train set - Male/Female and around ~50K image in the test set - Male/Female . I am using below to work , also tried to add few more layers and more units . Also, I am doing data augmentation and others provided from keras docs.

```
targetSize =64
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size =(3,3),input_shape=(targetSize,targetSize,3),activation ='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size =(3,3),activation ='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size =(3,3),activation ='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size =(3,3),activation ='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.6))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1,activation='sigmoid')

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                     shear_range = 0.2,
                     zoom_range = 0.2,
                     height_shift_range = 0.2,
                     width_shift_range = 0.2,
                     horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('<train_folder_loc>',
                                                 target_size = (img_size, img_size),
                                                 batch_size = batch_size_train,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('<test_folder_loc>',
                                            target_size = (img_size, img_size),
                                            batch_size = batch_size_test,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = <train_image_count>/batch_size_train,
                         epochs = n_epoch,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = <test_image_count>/batch_size_test,
                         use_multiprocessing = True,
                         workers=<mycpu>)
```

But with many combinations tried I am getting result like below , train acc and val acc is not moving ahead . I tried till 100 epoch and its almost like same.

```
11112/11111 [==============================] - 156s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5628 - acc: 0.7403 - val_loss: 0.6001 - val_acc: 0.6967
Epoch 2/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 156s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5516 - acc: 0.7403 - val_loss: 0.6096 - val_acc: 0.6968
Epoch 3/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5472 - acc: 0.7404 - val_loss: 0.5837 - val_acc: 0.6967
Epoch 4/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 155s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5437 - acc: 0.7408 - val_loss: 0.5850 - val_acc: 0.6978
Epoch 5/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5409 - acc: 0.7417 - val_loss: 0.5844 - val_acc: 0.6991
Epoch 6/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 155s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5386 - acc: 0.7420 - val_loss: 0.5828 - val_acc: 0.7011
Epoch 7/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5372 - acc: 0.7427 - val_loss: 0.5856 - val_acc: 0.6984
Epoch 8/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5347 - acc: 0.7437 - val_loss: 0.5847 - val_acc: 0.7017
Epoch 9/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5331 - acc: 0.7444 - val_loss: 0.5770 - val_acc: 0.7017
Epoch 10/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5323 - acc: 0.7443 - val_loss: 0.5803 - val_acc: 0.7037
Epoch 11/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5309 - acc: 0.7453 - val_loss: 0.5877 - val_acc: 0.7018
Epoch 12/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 155s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5294 - acc: 0.7454 - val_loss: 0.5774 - val_acc: 0.7037
Epoch 13/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5282 - acc: 0.7464 - val_loss: 0.5807 - val_acc: 0.7024
Epoch 14/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5276 - acc: 0.7467 - val_loss: 0.5815 - val_acc: 0.7033
Epoch 15/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 156s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5269 - acc: 0.7474 - val_loss: 0.5753 - val_acc: 0.7038
Epoch 16/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 154s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5263 - acc: 0.7477 - val_loss: 0.5825 - val_acc: 0.7039
Epoch 17/25
11112/11111 [==============================] - 155s 14ms/step - loss: 0.5249 - acc: 0.7485 - val_loss: 0.5821 - val_acc: 0.7037
```

I need your suggestion on this or any snippet to try .

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There are so many factors that can affect the outcome here, so we need to know more about how you setup the training. In general though, there is nothing that says that your architecture is guaranteed to get higher than 75% accuracy, on your dataset.

Comment: Sure. Give me few mins. Let me update the code.

Comment: @skalet  Updated with new edit.

Comment: I think it is actually moving... Maybe you need more digits to be sure and more epochs to see some important change

Comment: Still some ambiguities, for example, what is the value of `steps_per_epoch = <train_image_count>/batch_size_train`? Provide completely valid python code.

Comment: train_image_cont that was 0.3 million mentioned in question  batch_size for train and test is 48,

Comment: @m33n Any suggestion with the layers ? I tried adding more layers but I was getting same result..

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are overfitting on a small sample before trying to extend the network.
2. I would remove some/all of the `Dropout` layers and see if it improves performance. I think 3 Dropout layers is quite high.
3. Try reducing the learning rate.

Comment: Removing dropout is also not helping ..  Learning Rate I can try, I was using 0.001 previously ..

Answer (score 0):

Try and understand some of the basic principles of CNNs and how they are constructed; implement a simple one which works before arbitrarily putting in your own parameters.

For example, typically the number of filters in successive convolutions increases in powers of two (e.g. 32, 64, 128 etc). Your use of dropout also is questionable, 0.6 is very high, not to mention stacking the three dropouts like you have doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank You chris !

Answer (score -1):

Hmm if you look at it closely, its not that its not moviing. it is moving a bit. There are times when models only get better at a certain point no matter how long you train it, or even how much more layers you add. When that happens, it all boils down to the data. I think it would be best to determine what is hindering your model to improve. Also, my friend, training a good model doesn't happen overnight specially with real world data, much more with complex data such as images of humans.

I guess, if you are just following a tutorial which has achieved a better score than yours, you could check the version of packages their using, the data that you have, the steps they took and much more importantly the re run the model. There are instances where models could get different scores on different instances of training.

I suggest you should try playing with the layers more, or even use a different type of Neural Network. If not, you should try playing with your data more. 300k images are a lot but when it comes to image classification, it could be really hard.

Finally, I guess you could look into [transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) by tensorflow. You can read about it there. It works by retraining pre-made image recognition models. Keras has a [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) on Transfer learning too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion . Sure I will try reading and implementing those.

Comment: Okay then. Goodluck with that!